# How to release a viewController and his view inside of an NSMutableArray viewControllers?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ipad, memory, memory-management

I have a big problem with my memory management. A actually have a big magazine and every page it is render with his own PageViewController. My code it's totally based on PageControl sample of Apple Documentation, if you guys have seen sometime.

So, in the viewDidLoad of my "MainViewController" I create a NSMutableArray = self.viewControllers full of NSNull objects. And I call my `[self loadScrollViewPage:page];` for my first and second pages. When the user navigate into more pages, I call (from scrollViewDidScroll) more load `[self loadScrollViewPage:nextPage];` as the App will be need it. Also I implement a `unloadScrollViewPage:page` 'cause the magazine is so big, that the memory will be out if I don't.

So, this is my code:

```
- (void)loadScrollViewPage:(int)pageNumber
{
    if ((pageNumber < 0) || (pageNumber >= [self.viewControllers count]))
        return;

    PageViewController *controller = [self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:pageNumber];
    if ((NSNull *)controller == [NSNull null])
    {
        controller = [[PageViewController alloc] initWithPage:[self.pages objectAtIndex:pageNumber]];
        [self.viewControllers replaceObjectAtIndex:pageNumber withObject:controller];
        [controller release];
    }

    if (controller.view.superview == nil)
    {
        CGRect frame = mainpageScrollView.frame;
        frame.origin.x = 0;
        frame.origin.y = frame.size.height * pageNumber;
        controller.view.frame = frame;
        [mainpageScrollView addSubview:controller.view];
    }
}
- (void)unloadScrollViewPage:(int)pageNumber
{
    if ((pageNumber < 0) || (pageNumber >= [self.viewControllers count]))
        return;

    if ((NSNull *)[self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:pageNumber] != [NSNull null])
    {
        [[[self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:pageNumber] view] removeFromSuperview];
        [self.viewControllers removeObjectAtIndex:pageNumber];
        [self.viewControllers replaceObjectAtIndex:pageNumber withObject:[NSNull null]];
    }
}
```

The problem is, no matter how many times I call `unloadScrollViewPage`, the memory still increment size when I call `loadScrollViewPage` and never decrement with `unloadScrollViewPage`. So, when the user is going in the 10 page (of 300 pages, lol?) the memory size of my App is of 100Mb and of course, it crash :(

My questions are:

- Am I releasing memory correctly from my self.viewControllers NSMutableArray?
- The views of each controller that I put on they superview (the view of MainViewController) will release it when I removeObjectAtIndex:pageNumber from the self.viewControllers? If not, how can I do it? Is this my problem?

Thanks in advanced.

**EDIT:**

Looks like **Firoze Lafeer** was right at the beginning, the problem was my UIImage memory management and my views retained. I just manage to removeFromSuperview each UIView. For the images, looks like using `[UIImage imageNamed]` it implements a cache (that release it when ios wants ¬¬). I just change the way using `[UIImage imageWithData:imageData];` which doesn't implements cache and all my objects are happy now. Thanks everybody. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, when you add each view to the scrollview, the scrollview will retain that view. So you will have to remove each view as you unload each page.

BTW, I think you'll find that the view controllers themselves don't take up very much memory at all. The views are the bigger issue.

Comment: Ok, so if that view have several subviews, then I have to remove them each subview?… I actually removing that view from the scrollView where I put it, but the memory doesn't decrease. Any idea?

Comment: Removing a view will remove all of its subviews as well from the view hierarchy. If the views are still not being deallocated, you should check their history in Instruments. Actually, you can use Instruments to confirm this is where your memory is going in the first place. If you are loading images in your views, are you sure you managing those correctly?

Comment: Which component of Instruments can do that?

Comment: You can use Allocations. Look at the object list, filter for "MyBigView" or whatever, then click focus on that and you'll see the retain/release history. That's one way to do it. Or just looking at statistics, you may find the problem is a bunch of images and not the views themselves.

Comment: The problem looks to be a Bunch of Images that I display. An Image each view. While I'm going one next page more, the memory increase a lot (like 10 Mb by page. I have no idea what's going on :(

Comment: Well, images can take a lot of memory. That's not unusual. You can improve that by choice of image format and resolution and so on. But the other issue is make sure you are releasing the images when you don't need them (like when you remove that view). Instruments can help you figure out why that memory isn't being freed.

Comment: Looks like you are right at the beginning, the problem was my UIImage memory management. Using `[UIImage imageNamed]` it implements a cache (that release it when ios wants ¬¬). I just change the way using `[UIImage imageWithData:imageData];` which doesn't implements cache and all my objects are happy now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The rest of your code looks like it should behave the way you expect it however these two lines might not be right.

```
    [self.viewControllers removeObjectAtIndex:pageNumber];
    [self.viewControllers replaceObjectAtIndex:pageNumber withObject:[NSNull null]];
```

The first line is going to remove the object and decrement all the indexes above it by one, so your array will be one smaller.  Then you are calling replaceObject at the object that once was one index higher than the object you removed.  These two lines of code will decrease the size of your array by one every time it's called until you get an out of bounds exception when you go passed the actual length of the array.You can remove the removeObject line and replaceObject will release that object on it's own while leaving your array the same size.

This probably won't solve your problem though as it will decrement the retain counter the same way.  Perhaps it would help to post the code that calls these methods.

Comment: You are right. But yes, actually this doesn't solve my problem of memory.